# How to launch a command-line application without having to type the command?

Tags: alsa, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to write a python script that will launch `alsamixer`. `alsamixer` is a command-line application, that you typically launch by:

1. Opening up a Terminal.
2. Typing `alsamixer`.

I'm trying to make alsamixer something I can launch, so that after clicking it, it will launch a terminal with alsamixer already running before any physical interaction from me.

Comment: GNOME, KDE or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can launch an xterm which first runs a command via

```
xterm -e alsamixer
```

Armed with that knowledge you can easily make a script that launches the terminal:

```
echo '#!/usr/bin/env sh\n\nxterm -e alsamixer' > mixer ; chmod +x mixer
```

Move that script to your desktop or whatever. If you use a different terminal it might have different options, `-e` is fairly standard though.